# How to predict NFC ID on Android device

Tags: java, android, nfc, predict, uid

does anyone know how I can predict the next id on my android device. Because every time I go over the reader, I get a different id.

Answer (score 0):

It's random by design for security purposes because the design of NFC is that the ID only has to be different if multiple Tags are presented at the same time (NFC != RFID)

Comment: Thanks. I understand that but i'm trying to find code that can capture the incoming or current id, For example to set in textview.

Comment: Just read it on another device like you would for any other Tag ID, you cannot read your own ID.